# Reducing differences in xibs

Tags: version-control, interface-builder, xib

I've been noticing superfluous changes in my xib files with Interface Builder 3.2.1.

Here are a few of them:

```
-               <reference key="NSNextResponder"/>
+               <nil key="NSNextResponder"/>


-               <reference key="NSSuperview"/>


-       <array class="NSMutableArray" key="IBDocument.EditedObjectIDs">
-           <integer value="6"/>
-       </array>
+       <array class="NSMutableArray" key="IBDocument.EditedObjectIDs"/>
```

Can anyone tell me what these are, and are there  any tricks for avoiding them? I'd prefer my checkins to only describe changes I intentionally made.

Update: I wasn't clear in the original question, but these differences were caused by opening the file in Interface Builder and saving it without making a change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the changes are just superfluous, just revert the specific changes before checking in the NIB file if they bother you so much.

However, from the diff you posted, it looks like you changed some settings in the Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you didn't cause those? Perhaps when you were fiddling around with Interface Builder it made these changes? As you work in Interface Builder, it's actually editing and modifying the xib file, but I imagine you knew that, it's just that I'm not really sure I understand your question, sorry.

Comment: Most (all?) of these were caused by just opening the XIB and saving it without modification.